# Mental level of replicants -- as intelligent as engineers who made them?

Tags: blade-runner-series

It is clear that Batty is very intelligent but he is level A -- Pris is level B and indeed looks to Batty for leadership.

Is she less intelligent by design (my guess) or due to her maker's own limitations?

Would level B like an average human or less than average intellectually?

Comment: "*The NEXUS 6 Replicants were superior in strength and agility, and **at least equal in intelligence, to the genetic engineers who created them**.*"

Comment: @Valorum: I think that was an oversimplification because what would Level B intelligence be? Still above average for human, just not tops?

Comment: Leon has "Mental class: Level C", according to the file we see on the screen. It's not clear if that's above or below the average human. Certainly he doesn't *seem* that intelligent...

Comment: I don't think this one has an easy answer. It's obvious to me some replicants are more clever than others. Deckard and Batty are clever, though not scientist-level clever. Zhora and Pris seem more cunning than clever. Leon doesn't seem very clever at all. I think the opening statement means more "are roughly equal to clever humans, but YMMV". Also remember what Batty says to Sebastian: "we are not computers... we are physical" (whether he means Pris and himself, or replicants in general, is unclear). Any answer will probably be speculative.

Comment: Again speculation, but I think Pris and Leon are less intelligent on purpose, because their designated roles didn't require high intelligence. Pris is a "pleasure model" and Leon is "military/cargo loader", maybe those professions don't need much intelligence. But who knows?

Comment: Heck, we have trouble comparing *human* intelligence...

Comment: The Blade Runner RPG gives you the ability to boost your (human) character's intelligence up to "Level A (Experienced)", the same level as Nexus 6 Replicants

Comment: These 'mental class' definitions might be referring to their emotional ability too, not just intelligence. We see Leon as emotional, almost child-like, but he's not dumb.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "more human than human".

Comment: This is something I've always wondered, considering how... clueless Leon seems to be. Although it is questionable whether he knew he was in danger at the beginning, or if he simply got reckless.